# Detect if an image is on a malware url before displaying?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension displays images from external pages (just their favicons in case that matters). The problem is that sometimes after storing the link to these favicons the site in question becomes listed as malware. This causes my extension popup to show a malware warning when trying to display the image.

My question is, is there a way for me to prevent this from happening? Perhaps there is a way for me to test a url is safe before attempting to display the image?

Comment: There's no way to test whether a URL is safe.

I suggest to store a local copy of those images in your extension's storage area. An additional benefit is that the images are displayed faster, even on crappy network connections.

Comment: This might be the option I have to go for, but this doesn't help for all of the favicon urls I already have stored, it also means quite a lot more data storage (I sync this data to a remote server), which I would have liked to avoid. It also is possible to check if a url is safe using https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/ but the overhead of doing that for every favicon seems excessive.

Comment: [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) offers a convenient API for storing data, locally or synchronized. About the existing favicons: You could include a compatibility patch in your extension to convert the existing storage format to the new format.

Comment: I already have a server I sync the data to, and anyway the amount of data that chrome.storage allows me to sync (100k from what I can see) would not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your image urls by an URL of yourself. And let your server check if the url is a malware site.

I would say this would involve a couple of steps:

- Change the favicon links to a link of your server

  - On the server determine if an URL is a malware site. (So you have to find out what blacklist chrome is using.)
  - if it is a malware site show some favicon of your own
  - if it isn't, redirect to the actual site

Comment: I want to display a fairly large number of favicons at once, the overhead (processing on my server and the added latency) of sending all the requests through my server is something I wanted to avoid.